# Pass Value from Model as Parameter to Url.Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, form-submit

There is a model on my MVC Layout View  I need to pass the value of the ID field to a controller action, but I can't figure out how to do it.

I've tried:

```
{
     <label for="subfolder1"><a href="@Url.Action("ChangeUserCompany", "Home", new { id = @item.vchCompanyID.Value })" class="glyphicon-pencil">@item.vchCompanyName.Value</a></label>
     <input type="checkbox" id="subfolder1" checked="true" />
}
```

The ID is in `@item.vchCompanyID.Value`.  Can someone please tell me the property syntax to pass this to my controller action?

Thank you for any assistance!

Comment: your code looks fine ? What is not working ? Does `item.vchCompanyID` has a non null value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the @ and .Value inside the url parameters:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("ChangeUserCompany", "Home", new { id = item.vchCompanyID })" class="glyphicon-pencil">@item.vchCompanyName.Value</a>
```

also be sure that you are sending all the required parameters by the method

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href='@Url.Action("NewProposalPart2", "Proposal", null, null)?id=' + 
item.vchCompanyID}>
```

thats what you are looking for